# Can't block outbound traffic on port 80 using Windows 10 firewall

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall

I'm trying to block port 80 using Windows 10's firewall however it seems like no matter what I try I can still access HTTP sites.

I've been testing weather the port using the following powershell command: `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName portquiz.net -Port 80` which could be the issue however I have tried with other sites.

I firstly tried using the Windows defender GUI with the [following settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEcTE.png)

I then tried replicating the same rule using Powershell as an administrator with [this command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoBNI.png), but to no avail.

I also tried disabling all other firewall rules in case another is interfering and that didn't work either so I really don't know what I could be doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

you could have followed [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps):

```
PS C:\> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block Outbound Port 80" -Direction Outbound -RemotePort 80 -Protocol TCP -Action Block
```

It is sometimes useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this also didn't work :(
https://imgur.com/a/vVUzrZ2

Comment: Perhaps your browser has been granted access?